# sumar registros de inasistencias

Tags: mysql

Tengo las siguientes tablas en un sistema de asistencia escolar:

```
INASISTENCIA(idinasistencia,fecha,idtipoinassitencia,idalumno);
TIPOINASISTENCIA(idtipoinasistencia,valor);
```

¿Como puedo contar el valor total de inasistencia de un alumno dentro de un trimestre?
Osea desde marzo hasta mayo por ejemplo, cuando se arma la libreta se coloca el total de faltas digamos que tiene.

Probe lo siguiente:

```
SELECT   SUM(valor) as total 
FROM     tipoinasistencia 
WHERE    tipoinasistencia.idtipoinasistencia 
    IN ( SELECT idtipoinasistencia 
         FROM inasistencia 
         WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-08-08' AND '2016-09-17' 
           AND idalumno=3);
```

Pero parece ser me cuenta una sola vez por cada tipo de inasistencia y no por cada vez que aparece una inasistencia.

Que puedo hacer?

Comment: Usando **group by** amigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se hace con un simple **GROUP BY**

```
SELECT SUM(valor) as total,tipoinasistencia.idtipoinasistencia FROM
tipoinasistencia 
INNER JOIN inasistencia ON inasistencia.idtipoinasistencia = tipoinasistencia.idtipoinasistencia
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-08-08' AND '2016-09-17' AND idalumno=3 GROUP BY tipoinasistencia.idtipoinasistencia
```

Esa seria mi solucion a tu problema, aunque me ayudaria mas ver la estructura de tus tablas, para ayudarte mejor

Comment: yo tengo 3 tipos de inasistencias: falta entera, cuarto de falta, media falta. si el alumno tiene media falta hoy, un cuarto mañana, a fin de trimestre debe mostrarme 3/4 por ejemplo.